# How to fix this 404 Page Not Found shown in codeigniter in linux hosting?

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter

How can I do I used linux hosting and I've also change my controller name to lowercase letter

example: control file= page; class in controller name:Page and extend Fronend_controller->extent CI_controller.
But it still not work in mmy hosting how can I do

```
# Set PHP Time Zone:
#SetEnv TZ America/New_York
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#Option +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
 <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
  # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
  # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the rewrite url. Add this line

```
RewriteBase /address-to-your-codeigniter-folder/
```

after the line

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Mine is

```
RewriteBase /ci/
```

Where /is my localhost and ci is the folder that contains the codeigniter application.

Comment: Can you give a URL that is returning 404?